# Microphone inputs - specifics

Tags: microphone

What voltage and current can I insert into usual microphone input in PC ?

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. [Here](http://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/computer_microphone.php)'s an article with information you want.

[Here](http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/microphone_powering.html)'s another interesting article.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it'd depend on your setup, most computer microphone inputs are meant for passive microphones, which generally use 5V. If you want to pass input from the line out of a device, you'd want to use a line in port instead - microphone inputs are amplified, line ins arn't.

Do NOT use powered mics with a computer input, and if you're using an actual source, start with the volume ALL the way down and raise it slowly.

Currents in this case are VERY low, as with all audio gear

If you want a higher voltage, you can use 48V phantom powered mics with a breakout box - there's usb powered ones like the maudio fastrack, and others.